# Is it possible to write a generalizable equation to the birthday problem that doesn't use the complement?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to write the birthday problem, but instead of finding the likelihood of no shared birthdays, I want to find the total number of events/combinations of birthdays where a birthday is shared, and then divide that by the total number of combinations.

For example, for two people in the room. There are $365^2$ possible combinations, and $365$ of those share a birthday. For three people there are $365^3$ possible combinations and of them $398945$ of those share a birthday.

I wrote this formula here, but it stops working at 5 people and more.

$$\frac{365^{n - 1} + (365 \times 364^{n - 2})\left(\frac{n(n - 1)}{2} - 1\right)}{365^n}$$

The key part is the numerator which will find the total number of combinations with two shared birthdays. But this doesn't seem to work after 3 people. I thought it worked up to 4. But I was checking it with wolframalpha which was only giving 4 significant digits.

Is this possible? I realize it's not practical. But I want to know if there is a way to write it as a formula. I can't picture it past $4$ people.

Comment: The formula is OK, it's the numerical representation on the computer that might be an issue. What programming language are you using?

Comment: What does "total number of events" mean?  What do you mean by "events"?  Please [edit] your question to clarify.  The number of pairs is a random variable.  Are you looking to compute its expected value?  Its distribution?  Are you trying to compute the probability that there is at least one shared birthday?

Comment: "$3989454$" should be $398945$. But the formula doesn't even give a completely accurate answer for four people; the correct probability is about $0.016355912$ while the formula gives $0.016363398$.

Comment: @D.W. Total number of events is 365^n or the total possible combinations of birthdays. Ideally I want to find the total number of ways to get two people sharing a birthday when n people are in a room.

Comment: @DavidK This is likely as I was using wolfram to compare and it only gave 4 significant digits.

Comment: Please don't add information in the comments.  Instead, [edit] the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time and to address feedback, and so that people don't need to read the comments to understand the question.  We're trying to build an archive of well-written questions that will be useful to others in the future.

Comment: The question is too fuzzy. For 0 people all 365 days are empty. For 1 person there is 1 day. For 2 people 2 versions: (i) 2 distinct days (ii) one day of 2 persons. For 3 people 3 versions: (i) 3 distinct days (ii) 1 single day, 1 day with 2 people, (iii)  1 day with 3 persons. For 5 people 7 versions: (i) 5 distinct (ii) 3 distinct, 1 day with 2, (iii) 1 single, 2 days each with 2 people, (iv) 2 days with single persons, one day with 3 persons, (v) 1 day with 2 persons, 1 day with 3 persons, (vi) 1 day with 1 person, 1 day with 4 persons, (vii) 1 day with 5 persons.  Which of these count?